# Can't run spring project from eclipse, ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, m2eclipse

I'm having trouble running my spring project from inside Eclipse.

This is the error I get:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

Here are the Tomcat settings:

[image: Here are the settings]

I don't understand why it's not working, the spring classes are included in the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the spring-web jar. I see you're using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

NOTE: that the latest release is 3.0.5.RELEASE. Also, you can identify the spring project by the package, i.e. `org.springframework.web`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. I went to project properties/deployment assembly then added my spring library. I also have my spring library on my project build path.

Worked for me. Hope this helps :]